# How to find subgraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, cytoscape.js

I am trying to show a specific subgraph of a disconnected directed graph containing a selected node by the user. All parents, parents of parents... and children, children of children until roots and the leaves. I need to hide the rest of the graph.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is the subgraph user wanna show is connected

Comment: the subgraph to show is connected

Comment: hash the node which user wants to select and do a dfs on the graph and intersect this with the hashed nodes you gonna obtain your desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @aksam suggested, something like:

```
var selectedNode = cy.$('node:selected');
var visitedArr = [ selectedNode ];

cy.elements().bfs({ // or dfs
  roots: selectedNode,
  visit: function(i, depth, v, e, u){
    visitedArr.push( v );
  },
  directed: false // or your preference
});

var subgraph = cy.collection( visitedArr );

cy.batch(function(){
  cy.elements().not( subgraph ).addClass('hidden');
  subgraph.removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The maxkfranz answer gives me errors.

Based on his answer, this gives me the right solution :

```
var selectedNode = cy.$('node:selected');
var visitedArr = [ selectedNode ];

cy.elements().bfs({ // or dfs
  roots: selectedNode,
  visit:  function(v, e, u, i, depth){
    visitedArr.push( v );
  },
  directed: false // or your preference
});

var subgraph = cy.collection( visitedArr );

cy.batch(function(){
  cy.nodes().hide();
  subgraph.show();
});
```

Comment: the `subgraph` collection will contain two `selectedNode`s. One `selectedNode` is added by line 2 of the code. Another one `selectedNode` is added when it first visit the root node of `bfs()`. May cause unexpected behavior to `subgraph` collection in future code.